# Are meromorphic functions bounded "near" a pole?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I am trying to understand the concept of a [removeable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity).

Number three says

"There exists a neighbourhood of $a$ on which $f$ is bounded"

This is confusing me since to me a neighbourhood is just a set containing an open set w.o reference to size.

A pole for instance is not bounded arbitraraly close to it, yet poles are reamovable.

Does anyone have such an example or can explain where my reasoning fails.

Comment: How exactly are you proposing we remove poles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion “There exists a neighbourhood of $a$ on which $f$ is bounded” means that there exists a neighbourhood $N$ of $a$ such that the set $f(N)=\{f(z)\,|\,z\in N\cap\text{domain of }f\}$ is bounded.

For instance, if $f\colon\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ is defined by $f(z)=z$, then $0$ is a removable singularity and $f\bigl(D(0,1)\bigr)=D(0,1)\setminus\{0\}$, which is bounded.

By the way, poles are *not* removable singularities.

Comment: I was thinking about $\frac{sinz}{z}$ where I tought $z$ gave rise to a pole and the zero of $sin$ "canceld" it thus giving rise to conditon 4 on wikipedia. That was wrong to think about it in that way I guess. Also I was not aware of that this only had to apply to the domain of $f$.

Comment: @user21312 Indeed, the function $f\colon\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ defined by $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}z$ has a removable singularity at $0$, not a pole.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to Jose Carlos Santos answer, the classification of singularities goes like this:

1. Removable (aka good) singularities are points where the function is bounded near them,
2. Poles (aka almost good) are points where the limit of the function is $\infty$ and the last one are
3. essential singularities (extremely bad) which are points that don't fit to one of the previous cases.

There is a great exposition by Terence Tao [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/09/22/246a-notes-1-complex-differentiation/) about singularities where he explains in particular how the first two singularities can be "fixed".